# PDF Upload is not working in Android Webview and Browser

Tags: android, asp.net, html

PDF Upload is not working in Android Webview and Browser, I can able to upload all files like Png, Jpg, txt etc except pdf file

When I am going select the Pdf file using input type file, then it doesn't shows that selected file

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xlsx,.xls,image/*,.doc, .docx.,.ppt, .pptx,.txt,.pdf" runat="server" class="inputfile" />

<label for="file" runat="server" class="bcblue">Choose File</label>
```

This is working fine with desktop browser (Chrome, IE and Firefox) and MOTO E device only.

Comment: And it working fine from android version 5.1